# How to enable Header section in graphiql playground?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphiql

[image]

I am using the graphql-HTTP package. And there is no tab for passing tokens (headers) in the playground.
So how to enable it?

I'm declaring as below

```
 app.use(
      "/graphql",
      graphqlHTTP({
        schema: UserTypes,
        rootValue: UserResolver,
        graphiql: true,
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `graphqlHTTP` function comes from the [`express-graphql`](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/8b6ffc65776aa40d9e03f554425a1dc14840b165/README.md) package, not the [`graphql-http`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-http) package.

When using the `express-graphql` package and `graphqlHTTP` function. You can use [headerEditorEnabled](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/8b6ffc65776aa40d9e03f554425a1dc14840b165/README.md) option to enables the header editor

> An optional boolean which enables the header editor when `true`. Defaults to `false`.

E.g.

```js
const express = require('express');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`);

const root = {
  hello: () => {
    return 'Hello, World';
  }
};

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/graphql',
  graphqlHTTP((req) => {
    console.log('req.headers: ', req.headers)
    return {
      schema,
      rootValue: root,
      graphiql: { headerEditorEnabled: true }
    }
  })
);
const port = 4000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

The header editor will display

[image]

Send a graphql HTTP request, the logs:

```bash
Server is listening on http://localhost:4000
req.headers:  {
  host: 'localhost:4000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '42',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Microsoft Edge";v="113", "Chromium";v="113", "Not-A.Brand";v="24"',
  accept: 'application/json',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/113.0.1774.42',
  token: 'bearer 123',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
  origin: 'http://localhost:4000',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:4000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6'
}
```

You can access the `token` header from `req.headers.token`

Comment: How to enable the explorer tab to get available queries and mutations directly?
Also it is possible to add prefix in Request Header like { "Authorization" :  null }.